# count number of records per user between two time stamps

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two scenarios.

1: I want to count records from the table that have been entered today with particular userid. i.e. only the today entered stats shall be displayed.

2: i want to display the records with one week time span with particular userid. i.e. every time it displays the records one week time interval should be taken.

Below is my query:

```
$sql2=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total FROM tablename WHERE userid='$userid'");
```

to display the records

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
  {
  echo "<td>" . $row['total'] . "</td>";
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you have column with this date information. You can then use:

```
SELECT
    DATE(your_date_column), 
    COUNT(userid) AS total 
FROM tablename 
WHERE userid='$userid'
AND your_date_column BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE(your_date_column)
```

If you only want data of complete days then you've got to tweak the query a little bit, i.e. to exclude the first day of this interval.

If you want the totals of this week only without counts on daily basis you can use

```
SELECT
    userid,
    COUNT(userid) AS total 
FROM tablename 
WHERE userid='$userid'
AND your_date_column BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()
GROUP BY userid;
```

**Note**

Please have a look the [red box for the mysql_ extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and consider moving to mysqli or PDO. It's much better to use prepared statements with placeholders to bind your input values to than concatenation of sql strings.

Comment: it apepars to be working fine .. I am still confused it displays the records with current date on with one week time span ???

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. If you want the totals of the last week and not daily accounts then omit simply the GROUP BY. Then you get the totals of last week.

Comment: I forgot: you've got to omit the DATE(your_date_column) too. And better add GROUP BY userid.

Comment: to summarize:::::: for daily statst::::::: $sql6=$Db1->query("SELECT DATE(fecha), COUNT(user) AS total FROM table_name WHERE user='$username' AND fecha BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW()");

:::::::and for weekly stats ::::
$sql6=$Db1->query("SELECT DATE(fecha), COUNT(user) AS total FROM ads2_log WHERE user='$username' AND fecha BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND NOW() GROUP BY DATE(fecha)");  ::::::::: thanks to confirmation